# Find Cell address of a date in a Excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, date, openpyxl, xlrd

I have one excel sheet which has data for every date of the month. I am creating a python code to convert that data into the required format. For that, I need the cell address of the given Dates

For Example - [Dummy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLpHG.png)

If I want the cell address of 10/3/2020, then it should return C1 as the output which is the cell address of that date in the sheet.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try a VBA code:

```
Function Calc(objRange As Range, strDatr As Date)
  For Each objCell in objRange
    If objCell.Value == strDate Then
      Calc = objCell.Address
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

And call it like:

```
myCell = Calc("A1:G7","10/3/2020")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with python, I would use the library openpyxl and I would do it in this way :

```
import openpyxl

path = r'C:\PathToTheExcelFile\test.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active
```

First I check the size of the excel-file (To avoid to check all the empty cell,
maybe it has a better option than this one. But I assume that your excel file is not really big. If it is the case, surely there is better option.

```
i =1
j =1
cell_value = ws.cell(i, j).value
last_j = j
while cell_value is not None:
    last_j = j
    j+=1
    cell_value = ws.cell(i, j).value

i =1
j =1
last_i = i
while cell_value is not None:
    last_i = i
    i+=1
    cell_value = ws.cell(i, j).value
```

When I know the size of the Excel-file, I check in every cell if  it contains the value that we search:

```
My_value = datetime(2020, 3, 10, 0, 0)
for col in range(1,last_j+1):
    for row in range(1,last_i+1):
        cell_value = ws.cell(row, col).value
        if cell_value == My_value :
            i_goal = col
            j_goal = row
```

I did the assumption that your Excel File is an .XLSX. The second part can also be optimized. If you have a big excel file you will lose time to check all the cells. You can surely add a break in the for-loop.

i_goal and j_goal are the row and the columns number respectively that you are looking for. j_goal can be transformed as a letter if you prefer in order to obtain an Excel format.